# Elastic Database Client Library

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is the elastic database client library intended for use with shards other than those in Azure SQL? We have tested a hybrid cloud architecture where a single Shard Map database manages two databases. The first database is an Azure SQL database while the second is a SQL Server 2016 database on an Azure VM. Initial testing shows that the shard map has no problem with the database on the VM as long as it can reach the server. All the documentation/blogs/tutorials however only use examples with Azure SQL databases. Is there an issue if the shards are not all SQL Azure databases? It seems that the intended use of this library is for Azure SQL.

Other forums suggest that the library can be used for on premises sql server. But I have yet to find any examples/tutorials where a shard map manages servers distributed across Azure SQL and SQL Server on a VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have a number of customer now asking for official support of the client library for SQL Server. Yes, it does work with SQL Server in addition to Azure SQL Database, but the SQL Server scenario is not officially supported by CSS and the EULA. Can you please send me a direct email to learn more about your scenario and see how we can help with providing some official support. ddove(at)microsoft(dot)com